# Select the result of replacement - Word Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, full-text-search

I want to get and select the result of a find and replacement macro and do some operations on it.

Say, this is the text: ‎`\[abc\]‎`, I want to convert it to `abc` and then select `abc`.

Here is the code:

```vb
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "(\\\[)(*)(\\\])"
        .Replacement.Text = "\2"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Cut
```

Here in the last line, `Selection.Cut` gives an error that the Selection is empty.
I want to select the output of the replacement and Cut it.

From my repository [Amin MSWord VBA macros](https://github.com/aminya/Amin-MSWord-VBA-macros)

Comment: The problem is that you're using `wdReplaceAll`. This does not move to anything - it simply replaces everything that matches in the document.

Comment: @CindyMeister What should I do instead? removing `wdReplaceAll` fixes the issue?

Comment: Using only `Selection.Find.Execute` gives the `Run-time error 4605, the method or property is not available because the object is empty`.

Comment: Sorry, I was on a mobile device, before... Use `wdReplaceOne` instead, and it will make one replacement, putting the Selection (or Range if `Range` is used, instead) at that point. I've written it up as an answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wdReplaceAll` as the Replacement "target" doesn't jump to individual "hits", which is why the `Selection` is not picking up anything.

Use `wdReplaceOne`, instead, and the `Selection` (or `Range` object, if that is used) will move to the found content.

You might want to test whether something was actually found before issuing the `.Cut` command as that could have unexpected consequences if nothing is found (delete content at the point where the macro was initiated). For example:

```
Sub FindReplaceAndCut()
    Dim found As Boolean

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "(\\\[)(*)(\\\])"
        .Replacement.Text = "\2"
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    found = Selection.Find.Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
    If found Then
        Selection.Cut
    End If
End Sub
```